# How to have a timer that only ticks down if the page is on top?

Tags: javascript, html

The redirect portion of my site currentaly ticks down and then redirects the user, how do I make it where the window has to stay on top for the timer to tick down then redirect?

Comment: Do you mean the timer tick down only when the page stay at the top?

Comment: @Chaska yea thats it

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="{second}; url={Your Url}">
```

Example following code will redirect to google after 3 sec.

```
    <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="3; url=https://google.com">
```

Comment: This is the same thing as I just stated I ALREADY have.